# I'm getting an expception error in the console when coding selenium C# app "Error returned"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm getting this error in the process of running selenium code file, the console only reports the error as below, but the program is still running normally, but I don't understand what this error is? Guys if you have encountered this error please help me answer it

```
Error returned: <dictionary: 0x1f806c980> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
        "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x1f806cb18> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}
```

Comment: This question needs more information before community can help, as there is not enough to make it reproducible. Follow this guide: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example